# Regex to match the url pattern in nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am working on a node application, i need a regex to match the url pattern and get information out of the url, suggest the possible solutions.

```
This are the url patterns:
1) www.mysite.com/Paper/cat_CG10
2) www.mysite.com/White-Copy-Printer-Paper/cat_DP5027
3) www.mysite.com/pen/directory_pen?
4) www.mysite.com/Paper-Mate-Profile-Retractable-Ballpoint-Pens-Bold-Point-Black-Dozen/product_612884
5) www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222?categoryId=12328

These is what is want from the above url:
1) name= "cat" value="CG10"
2) name= "cat" value="DP5027"
3) name= "directory" value ="pen"
4) name="product" value ="612884"
5) name="directory" value="22222" params = {categoryId : 12328}

I want a regex which can match the url pattern and get the values like name, value and params out of the urls.
```

Answer (score 1):

This function does the trick for the urls and desired matches you've provided. It will also parse out an infinite number of query parameters.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8a9nK/

```
function parseUrl(url)
{
    var split = /^.*\/(cat|directory|product)_([^?]*)\??(.*)$/gi.exec(url);
    var final_params = {};
    split[3].split('&').forEach(function(pair){
       var ps = pair.split('=');
       final_params[ps[0]] = ps[1];
    });
    return {
        name: split[1], 
        value: split[2], 
        params: final_params
    };
}
```

Explanation

`^` Start from the beginning of the string
`.*` Match any number of anything (The beginning of the url we don't care about)
`\/` Match a single backslash (The last one before the things we care about)
`(cat|directory|product)`  Match and capture the word cat OR directory OR product (This is our *name*)
`_`  Match an underscore (The character separating our *name* and *value*)
`([^?]*)` Match and capture any number of anything EXCEPT a question mark (This is our *value*)
`\??`  Match a question mark if it exists, otherwise don't worry about it (The start of a potential query string)
`(.*)`  Match and capture any number of anything (This is the entire query string that we will split into *param* later)
`$`  Match the end of the string

Comment: can you explain this part "/^.*\/(cat|directory|product)_([^?]*)\??(.*)$/gi"

Comment: Yep, the solution has been modified to add an explanation.

Comment: if isPartial is present how to get just that query parameter www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222?categoryId=12328&isPartial=true

Comment: The function will return an object with the properties: name, value, and params. You can access the isPartial parameter like this ```var obj = parseUrl('www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222?categoryId=12328&isPartial=true'); var isPartial = obj.params.isPartial```

Comment: i have url like http://www.staples.com/Duracell-DL2430-30-Volt-Lithium-Battery/product_448696#id='dropdown_37439', and my regex is /^.*\/(cat|directory|product)_([^?#]*)\??(.*)$/gi i am getting result like {"name":"product","value":"448696","params":{"#id":"'dropdown_37439'"}}, my expected result is {"name":"product","value":"448696","params":{"id":"'dropdown_37439'"}}

Comment: i want a regex for the fallowing url pattern "http://api.staples.com/v1/product/10001.json?zipCode=123&storeId=123&catalogId=123& locale=en&client_id=123"

Answer (score 0):

The regex below would have in its match groups 1 & 2 the desired values

```
/^\/[^\/]+\/([^_]+)_([^\/_?]+).*$/
```

Explained piece by peace on the string `/HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-m7-j010dx-173-Touc‌​h-Screen-Refurbished-Laptop/product_8000`:

- `^`: from beginning
- `\/`: match a `/`
- `[^\/]+`: match everything until a `/` (`HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-m7-j010dx-173-Touc‌​h-Screen-Refurbished-Laptop`)
- `\/`: match a `/`
- `([^_]+)` match and capture the value before the `_` (`product`)
- `_`: match a `_`
- `([^\/_?]+)` match and capture the value after the `_` stopped by a `?`, `_` or `/` (`8000`)
- `.*` match until the end - if there is anything
- `$` end

Example:

```
var re = /^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^_]+)_([^\/_?]+).*$/;
var matches = re.exec('www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222?categoryId=12328');
console.log(matches.splice(1));
```

output:

```
["directory", "22222"]
```

Comment: i tried the example you have given. var match = req.url.match(/^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^_]+)_([^\/_?]+).*$/);
 console.log(match); i am getting null in console, what could be the possible reason?

Comment: I should see the url that did not match as well to give you an appropriate answer

Comment: this is the url "/HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-m7-j010dx-173-Touch-Screen-Refurbished-Laptop/product_8000" which i get from req.url in nodejs request object.

Comment: well of course, since in your question the provided url examples were starting with `www.mysite.com` and my regex takes that into consideration as well (see example)

Comment: Here, updated the regex: 
`/^\/[^\/]+\/([^_]+)_([^\/_?]+).*$/.exec("/HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-m7-j010dx-173-Touch-Screen-Refurbished-Laptop/product_8000" ).splice(1)`

Comment: yes that's correct, but the req.url will not have the domain name. can you please modify the regex for the url pattern "/HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-m7-j010dx-173-Touch-Screen-Refurbished-Laptop/product_8000?ispartial=true"

Comment: i have a url like this "http://www.staples.com/Duracell-DL2430-30-Volt-Lithium-Battery/product_448696#id='dropdown_37439" the following regex "/^.*\/(cat|directory|product)_([^?#]*)\??(.*)$/gi" will give result like {"name":"product","value":"448696","params":{"#id":"'dropdown_37439'"}}. i need result like {"name":"product","value":"448696","params":{"id":"'dropdown_37439'"}}

Answer (score 0):

use the `url` module to help you, not everything needs to be done with a regex :)

```
var uri = require( 'url' ).parse( 'www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222?categoryId=12328', true );
```

which yields (with other stuff):

```
{ 
  query: { categoryId: '12328' },
  pathname: 'www.mysite.com/22222/directory_22222'
}
```

now to get your last part:

```
uri.pathParams = {};
uri.pathname.split('/').pop().split('_').forEach( function( val, ix, all ){
    (ix&1) && ( uri.pathParams[ all[ix-1] ] = val );
} );
```

which yields:

```
{ 
  query: { categoryId: '12328' },
  pathParams: { directory: '22222 },

  ... a bunch of other stuff you don't seem to care about
}
```